# Function Pointers as Event Callbacks in a st

Tags: c++, events, callback, function-pointers

I am currently trying to implement an event system where layers can subscribe to certain event types. I am struggling with function pointers for the callback methods. In the layer.h file I have the OnEvent function and a function pointer which looks like this:

```
    void OnEvent(const Event& e);
    void(Engine::Layer::*m_EventCallback)(const Event& e);
```

In the constructor of a layer I simply do this:

```
m_EventCallback = OnEvent;
```

To keep track of which layer subscribed to which EventType I have defined a struct as folling:

```
struct CallbackData {
    EventType type;
    void(Engine::Layer::*OnEvent)(const Event& e);
    int layerID;
    bool isActive;
};
```

I have an EventDispatcher and its dispatch function looks something like this:

```
bool EventDispatcher::Dispatch(const Event& e)
{
    for (CallbackData& calldata : m_Callbacks) {
        if (calldata.type == e.GetEventType() && calldata.isActive) {
            calldata.OnEvent(e);
        }
    }
    
    //TODO work on this so it only returns true if the event has been properly dispatched
    return true;
}
```

There is also a subscribe function which creates an instance of CallbackData and pushes it into a vector which looks like this:

```
void EventDispatcher::Subscribe(EventType type, void(Engine::Layer::*OnEvent) 
(const Event& e), int layerID)
{
    CallbackData temp = { type, OnEvent, layerID, true };
    m_CallbackInsert = m_Callbacks.emplace(m_CallbackInsert, temp);
}
```

So if the type is of callback data is the same as the event references type the OnEvent function should get called via the function pointer.
The function pointer defintion needs to have Engine:: which is just a namespace and Layer which is the class where the OnEvent lies. I dont know why it needs the namespace because everything I do here is defined in the namespace.
But the main question is how do I properly define the function pointer and then call it the way showcased here?

The exact error message is this:

```
expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have(pointer-to-)function type
```

Please dont link sites with already implemented event systems. I have already looked at those and didnt really understand much. Thats why I want to do it myself so I do understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The syntax for acquiring a pointer-to-member is `&ClassName::MemberName`. There is no implicit conversion like in the pointer-to-function case.

Comment: You're also going to need an instance of `Layer` to call the function of. A pointer-to-member does not belong to a specific instance, but must be derefenced relative to an object.

Comment: Would it make sense to add a Layer pointer to the CallbackData struct and then receive the function pointer of that layer pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you're doing...

You have an EventDispatcher, and he needs to keep a registry of possible callbacks to make. I'm going to cut & paste a little code I use then explain it.

First, this is the relevant portion of my Route object.

```
class Route {
public:
    typedef std::function<void(const HTTPServerRequest &, HTTPServerResponse &)> Callback;

    Callback callback;
};

class Router {
public:
    void addRoute(const std::string &method, const std::string &path, Route::Callback callback);

};
```

That part works about how you would expect and doesn't require anything special. This creates an array of Route objects, with the callback method being given the callback passed into addRoute(). When I want to dispatch on this particular route:

```
route->callback(request, response);
```

You probably know that part, too.

For my code, I'm making method calls into an object. To pass that, you have two choices. The first is to use std::bind() -- which I really dislike.

So I use lambdas.

```
addRoute("GET", "/ping", [=](const HTTPServerRequest &request, HTTPServerResponse &response) { ping(request, response); } );
```

Is this absolutely the most efficient? I have no idea. But performance isn't ultra-sucky, so this is what I do.

Basically, I keep std::function<> pointers, and those are really easy to use. You can pass a lambda as a std::function<> as long as the signature matches.

The other choice is to use std::bind -- which, as I said, I don't like, mostly because I think it's uglier than using a lambda. But that's definitely an opinion, not a fact. Using std::bind may be a better way, but I don't have any code to show you doing it that way.

I'm not entirely sure this actually solves the confusion you're having, but if it's close, just comment, and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I'm going to add a comment. You'll notice I'm passing by value with the [=] part. The only thing being passed in this case is "this". Be very careful about passing by reference when using lambdas that are effectively "call later" as your references might no longer be valid. Pass-by-value is safer. Yes, I spent a day and a half one day realizing what a mistake I'd made when I did [&] on what is effectively a future call.